# Puppeteer can´t find the absolute path of the page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I`m trying to make a puppeteer web-scraping script with javascript, that allow me to get the email of many course sellers on that site and when I try to make it click on one, it return me an error of "Evaluation failed", i`m using this example :(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/puppeteer/puppeteer_absolute_xpath.htm), and i allready tried in my machine and it works, my guess is that im not giving the right path but in the example they tell you to just copy the absolute path of the element you want to click it and it should work. (sorry for my poor english, not my first language) Anyway Here is my code:

````
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function robo(){

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false, defaultViewport: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://app-vlc.hotmart.com/market/search?categoryId=25&page=1&userLanguage=PT_BR');

  await page.type('[data-test-id="login-email"]', 'my e-mail')
  await page.type('[data-test-id="login-password"]', 'my password')
 
  await page.click('[data-test-id="login-submit"]')
  
  await page.waitForTimeout(7000)
    await page.click("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[2]//div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]")[0]

    await page.waitForTimeout(4000)
    //obtain URL after click
    console.log(await page.url())
 }
    
  //browser.close();



   //await browser.close();
  

  robo();```
````

Comment: Better to use `waitForNavigation` than `waitForTimeout` and avoid the huge browser-generated selectors that are hyper-specific and easily broken. I'm not really clear what you're trying to accomplish here though. Can you clarify? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen The script's ultimate goal is to return me some emails from the sellers on this site, but for now all it does is click on an element (a llink) and return me the url of the page. And I'm using the absolute path because the elements I'm trying to click have no way to distinguish from each other, their classes are practically identical, and that is no way that i can use the ids or calsses to select then.